# recover encryption surrogate key

Tags: java, encryption, aes, password-encryption, secret-key

I am attempting to implement [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/encrypting-user-data-using-password-and-forgot-my-password) encryption scheme with AES encryption.

Basically it goes as follows:

1. user data is encrypted with a surrogate key (surrogateKey)
2. the surrogate key is XORed with a key derived from the password
   (passwordKey) and stored (storedKey)
3. when the key is needed (to encrypt or decrypt user data) the storedKey is retrieved from the DB and XORed again with the freshly generated passwordKey to recover the surrogateKey

Except, I must be doing something wrong in implementation, because I can never seem to recover a valid surrogateKey and any attempt at decryption is giving me a BadPaddingException.

The code below demonstrates the issue. Sorry if it's a bit long, but you should be able to just copy and paste it into your IDE.`

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class SurrogateTest {
    private static final String alphanumeric =
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                    + "1234567890"
                    + "!#$%&()+*<>?_-=^~|";

    private static String plainText = "I am the very model of a modern major general";
    private static String cipherText = "";
    private static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    private static byte[] salt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // arguments are password and recovery string
        if (args.length > 1) {
            System.out.println("password: " + args[0] + "; recovery: " + args[1]);
        }
        String password = args[0];

        // passwordKey
        SecretKey passwordKey = getKey(password);
        System.out.println("passwordKey: " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(passwordKey.getEncoded()));

        // Generate surrogate encryption key from random string
        String rand = randomString(24);
        SecretKey surrogateKey = getKey(rand);
        byte[] surrogateByteArray = surrogateKey.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("surrogate: " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(surrogateByteArray));

        // encrypt plainText
        System.out.println("text to encrypt: " + plainText);
        cipherText = encryptWithKey(plainText, surrogateKey);

        // XOR surrogateKey with passwordKey to get storedKey
        SecretKey storedKey = xorWithKey(surrogateKey, passwordKey);
        String storedKeyString = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(storedKey.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("storedKey: " + storedKeyString);

        byte[] storedKey2Array = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(storedKeyString);
        SecretKey storedKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(storedKey2Array, 0, storedKey2Array.length, "AES");
        String storedKey2String = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(storedKey2.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("storedKey->String->key->string: " + storedKey2String);

        // recover surrogateKey from storedKey2
        SecretKey password2Key = getKey(password);
        System.out.println("password2Key: " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(password2Key.getEncoded()));
        SecretKey surrogate2Key = xorWithKey(storedKey2, password2Key);
        System.out.println("surrogate2 (recovered): " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(surrogate2Key.getEncoded()));

        // decrypt text
        String decryptedText = decryptWithKey(cipherText, surrogate2Key);
        System.out.println("decryptedText: " + decryptedText);
    }

    private static SecretKey xorWithKey(SecretKey a, SecretKey b) {
        byte[] out = new byte[b.getEncoded().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.getEncoded().length; i++) {
            out[i] = (byte) (b.getEncoded()[i] ^ a.getEncoded()[i % a.getEncoded().length]);
        }
        SecretKey outKey = new SecretKeySpec(out, 0, out.length, "AES");

        return outKey;
    }

    private static String randomString(int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            sb.append(alphanumeric.charAt(rnd.nextInt(alphanumeric.length())));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // return encryption key
    private static SecretKey getKey(String password) {
        try {
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            salt = new byte[16];
            random.nextBytes(salt);

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            // obtain secret key
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            return secret;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String encryptWithKey(String str, SecretKey secret) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
            AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
            byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8")); // encrypt the message str here

            // concatenate salt + iv + ciphertext
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            outputStream.write(salt);
            outputStream.write(iv);
            outputStream.write(encryptedText);

            // properly encode the complete ciphertext
            String encrypted = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(outputStream.toByteArray());
            return encrypted;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String decryptWithKey(String str, SecretKey secret) {
        try {
            byte[] ciphertext = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str);
            if (ciphertext.length < 48) {
                return null;
            }
            salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertext, 0, 16);
            byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertext, 16, 32);
            byte[] ct = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertext, 32, ciphertext.length);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ct);

            return new String(plaintext, "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This scheme is strange and hard to follow, and I think brittle and insecure for some parameters. I think the basic problem is that you have made the `salt` array an instance field instead of something returned from the `getKey()` method. Furthermore you have opted to reuse `getKey()` for generating the surrogate key, instead of something more direct and straightforward. The salt generated from the second use of `getKey()` overwrites the salt generated from the first, which is the value you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the posted code shows that `surrogate2 (recovered)` is different from `surrogate`. It should be obvious this is badly wrong. The reason is that at encryption you derive the 'password' (wrapping) key using a random salt and write that salt at the beginning of your data blob; at decryption you **derive the unwrapping key using a *new* salt** and then read the correct salt from the blob and totally ignore it. This means your unwrapping key is wrong, so your unwrapped data key is wrong, so your decryption is wrong.

PS: the random key used to directly encrypt and decrypt the data is usually called a 'data' key (as I just did) or DEK (abbreviation for Data Encryption or Encrypting Key), or a more specific term like 'session key' or 'message key' (in this case), or 'working key' or 'transient key' to emphasize its limited scope. It is not usually called 'surrogate'. And using PBKDF2 to derive this data key from a strongly random string is a waste of time; just use `SecureRandom_instance.nextBytes(byte[])` directly for the data key.